# Text doesn't accept new FontWeight of modified TextStyle

Tags: flutter, text-styling, textstyle

I have a `TextStyle` called `headline2`, which is bold. Now I want to have a text with `headline2`, but not in bold. I can modify `headline2` with `textTheme.headline2!.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal);`or I use `apply(fontWeightDelta: -3)`. Either way, if I use the new `TextStyle` in a `Text` or a `TextSpan`, it still shows up bold, even tho the new `TextStyle` has a `FontWeight` of 3.

```
   Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: GlobalSpacing.s),
                      child: ListView.separated(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                    const Divider(
                      thickness: 1,
                    ),
                    itemCount: controller.currentStep + 3,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          (controller.currentStep + 3 - 1 != index) ?
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(GlobalSpacing.m, 0.0, GlobalSpacing.m, 0.0),
                            child: Text.rich(
                              TextSpan(
                                style: textTheme.headline2,
                                text: "Text to be bold",
                                children: <TextSpan>[
                                  TextSpan(
                                style: textTheme.headline2!.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                                    text: "text to be normal",
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            /*
                            Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Text("Bold", style: textTheme.headline2),
                              const Spacer(),
                              Text("Not bold", style: textTheme.headline2!.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                            ],
                          ), */
                          ) :
                      createCurrentNodeWidget(textTheme),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                    ),
                    ),
```

Comment: do you add all the `ttf` type of your font? I mean did you add the normal type of that specific font in `yaml` file?

Comment: yamel fiel = yaml field?

Comment: that was typo, I mean yaml file.

Comment: That's not it, the normal type exists.

Comment: could you include your yaml file?